# Files reopen on process demonization

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I found in [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) the next piece of code related to process demonization:

```
  files_to_reopen = []
  ObjectSpace.each_object(File) do |file|
    files_to_reopen << file unless file.closed?
  end

  ::Process.daemon(true, true)

  files_to_reopen.each do |file|
    begin
      file.reopen file.path, "a+"
      file.sync = true
    rescue ::Exception
    end
  end

  [$stdout, $stderr].each do |io|
    File.open(options[:logfile], 'ab') do |f|
      io.reopen(f)
    end
    io.sync = true
  end
  $stdin.reopen('/dev/null')
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb#L191-L212

**I can't understand why do we have to reopen files as far as we inherit file descriptors on double fork? Does some specific case exist to do this?** Authors of the ["Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739) book, chapter "Daemon Processes", say **only** about closing the **unneeded** file descriptors:

> 5. Unneeded file descriptors should be closed. This prevents the daemon from holding open any descriptors that it may have inherited from its parent (which could be a shell or some other process). We can use our open_max function (Figure 2.17) or the `getrlimit` function (Section 7.11) to determine the highest descriptor and close all descriptors up to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe much of that code was inspired by Unicorn.  Eric Wong, author of Unicorn, is Mr. Linux in the Ruby world and usually knows all the tricks to do daemonization correctly.

Of course, in the broader picture, don't daemonize.  You should start Sidekiq with a proper process supervisor: systemd, upstart, runit, foreman, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Mike ‍♂️ Funny, I have got pretty the same answer in [`sneakers`](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/issues/334#issuecomment-375895796) – don't daemonize, delegate it to init system. As far as the smartest people consider to run demonization outside of the application and try to avoid this responsibility inside, isn't it right to drop `-d, :daemon` option entirely and force developers/operations to use an init system for that? Every *nix distro has init system.

Comment: Legacy compatibility but it's something I will consider dropping in Sidekiq 6.

Comment: Now everything is clear for me, really appreciate, thank you ‍♂️